# Not able to iterate through my object using for of loop over an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate through an object but getting an error

```js
const myObj = {
  number1: 4,
  number2: 10
}
for (const key of myObj) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${myObj[key]}`);
}
```

but instead getting a console error

Comment: *What* console error?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually making a very minor mistake. You are creating an object and using **for.. of** for that but **for..of** is use to iterate over an array. Use **for..in** instead which iterates over an object keys.

Here's your working demo:

```
const myObj = {
  number1: 4,
  number2: 10
}
    for (const key in myObj) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${myObj[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead of [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

The **`for...in` statement** iterates over all [enumerable
    properties](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by [Symbol](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)s),
  including inherited enumerable properties.

The **`for...of` statement** creates a loop iterating over [iterable
    objects](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol), including: built-in [`String`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [`Array`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), array-like
  objects (e.g., [`arguments`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
  or [`NodeList`](/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), [`TypedArray`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), [`Map`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map),
  [`Set`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with
  statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

Try below.

```js
const myObj = {
  number1: 4,
  number2: 10
}
for (const key in myObj) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${myObj[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [**of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with [**in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

[**for...of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is used in  String, Array, array-like objects.

Whereas [**in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is an **operator** that **returns** `true` if the specified property is in the `specified object`.

```js
const myObj = {
  number1: 4,
  number2: 10
}
for (const key in myObj) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${myObj[key]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is using `for ... of` instead of `for... in` in your loop. To iterate through object I think that using Object methods is better to process your data:

```
Object.entries(myObj2).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

You can also use keys method that gives you only the key and values that gives you only the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's good variant, this works perfect:

```
const myObj = {
  number1: 4,
  number2: 10,
};

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(`${key}: ${myObj[key]}`);
});
```